# Postgresql Mirror a table schema in another table

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table `asset_historical_data` in a postgresql database with historical minutely asset data.

| timestamp | asset_ticker | asset_price | asset_market_cap_bn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02/28/2022 10:00:00 | ABC | 7.77 | 1.01342 |
| 02/28/2022 10:00:00 | XYZ | 10.03 | 2.12233 |
| 02/28/2022 10:01:00 | ABC | 8.77 | 1.71342 |
| 02/28/2022 10:01:00 | XYZ | 10.05 | 2.13233 |

However, this table is quite large and in production we only need hourly asset data. I don't wanna drop any data that we collect. So, I am thinking of creating a new table called `asset_historical_data_filtered` which will only have hourly asset data like follows:

| timestamp | asset_ticker | asset_price | asset_market_cap_bn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02/28/2022 10:00:00 | ABC | 7.77 | 1.01342 |
| 02/28/2022 10:00:00 | XYZ | 10.03 | 2.12233 |

I want this new table to mirror the schema of the `asset_historical_data` table. In particular, I want any schema changes in the `asset_historical_data` table (such as addition of a column) to be reflected on the `asset_historical_data_filtered` table. This is necessary cause both tables essentially contain the same data but with different granularity. Is that possible in postgresql?

I use alembic to manage schema revisions, so a solution with alembic will be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/ddl-inherit.html)

```
create table asset_historical_data_filtered ()
 INHERITS (asset_historical_data);
```

Note that a query on the parent table will include records from children. If you don't want this, some possible options are:

1. Use the `ONLY` keyword when query the parent

   ```
   select * from only asset_historical_data;
   ```
2. Make a base parent table, both `asset_historical_data` and `asset_historical_data_filtered` inherit from it.
3. Insert the data generated in 0th minute and other times into different tables.

Please note the following limitation (copied from official documentation)

> A serious limitation of the inheritance feature is that indexes (including unique constraints) and foreign key constraints only apply to single tables, not to their inheritance children. This is true on both the referencing and referenced sides of a foreign key constraint.